# How to run the executable with Rust and Amethyst

Tags: rust, amethyst

So I followed the Amethyst Pong tutorial and am now building a little Game of Life program. It works fine if I run it with `cargo run` but if I do `cargo build` and then run

```sh
$ .\target\debug\game_of_life.exe
```

I get the error:

```
Error: Error { inner: Inner { source: None, backtrace: None, error: ConfigError(File(Os { code: 3, kind: NotFound, message: "The system cannot find the path specified." })) } }
```

If it was not already clear I am on Windows 10. I also created a blank rust project and tried running the executable of that and it worked fine:

```sh
$ cargo new temp
$ cd temp
$ cargo build
$ .\target\debug\temp.exe
Hello, world!
```

steps to reproduce (must have cargo and vulkan installed):

```sh
$ cargo install amethyst_tools
$ amethyst new temp
$ cd temp
$ cargo build
$ .\target\debug\temp.exe
Error: Error { inner: Inner { source: None, backtrace: None, error: ConfigError(File(Os { code: 3, kind: NotFound, message: "The system cannot find the path specified." })) } }
```

note that this:

```sh
$ amethyst new temp
$ cd temp
$ cargo run
```

works fine

Versions:

```sh
$ amethyst --version
Amethyst CLI 0.10.0
$ cargo --version
cargo 1.43.0 (3532cf738 2020-03-17)
```

Any ideas or any more information I should provide?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your main function calls [application_root_dir](https://github.com/amethyst/amethyst/blob/master/examples/pong/main.rs#L48) which is part of Amethyst.
The definition of [application_root_dir](https://github.com/amethyst/amethyst/blob/8e49449af3b9c621f73a92addbac7572084b5af3/amethyst_utils/src/app_root_dir.rs#L20) shows that it is either using `CARGO_MANIFEST_DIR` or the location of your executable as your root path (which is later used to find assets and configuration). When you invoke `cargo run`, it sets `CARGO_MANIFEST_DIR` to the directory of the currently built crate's Cargo.toml, whereas if you invoke the binary directly `CARGO_MANIFEST_DIR` does not get set at all (so it will try to use `.\target\debug` as the base-path to find configs/assets).

You can either copy the binary to the location of your `Cargo.toml` or set `CARGO_MANIFEST_DIR` manually, and then you should be able to execute your binary directly.